# freebsd customized port tree can not build ports from category level

Tags: freebsd, ports

Freebsd 9.1 RC3

just for clarification first: the top level is at /usr/ports, the category level is at /usr/ports/devel

I am working on customized ports tree. Basically, just trim the original whole ports tree to what we need. And, for the most part, it is the same, like GIDs, UIDs, Mk/, Tools/, Templates, and in term of Makefile, I just change SUBDIR to what we need.

General Problem: for each individual ports, like running 'make install clean' at /usr/ports/devel/protobuf, everything works. But, the thing is that running 'make install clean' at category level, it breaks.

Actual Problem:
run 'make install clean -DBATCH' at usr/ports/devel

```
  ....
  Usage: ./help2man.h2m.PL [--quiet] [--stdout|--output=FILE] [--locale=STRING]    [--message-     
 dir=DIR]
 gmake[1]: *** [help2man.el.h2m] Error 255
 gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/ports/misc/help2man/work/help2man-1.40.12'
 Option include requires an argument
 `help2man' generates a man page out of `--help' and `--version' output.

 Usage: help2man [OPTION]... EXECUTABLE

 -n, --name=STRING       description for the NAME paragraph
 -s, --section=SECTION   section number for manual page (1, 6, 8)
 -m, --manual=TEXT       name of manual (User Commands, ...)
 -S, --source=TEXT       source of program (FSF, Debian, ...)
 -L, --locale=STRING     select locale (default "C")
 -i, --include=FILE      include material from `FILE'
 -I, --opt-include=FILE  include material from `FILE' if it exists
 -o, --output=FILE       send output to `FILE'
 -p, --info-page=TEXT    name of Texinfo manual
 -N, --no-info           suppress pointer to Texinfo manual
 -l, --libtool           exclude the `lt-' from the program name
     --help              print this help, then exit
     --version           print version number, then exit

  EXECUTABLE should accept `--help' and `--version' options and produce output on
  stdout although alternatives may be specified using:

   -h, --help-option=STRING     help option string
   -v, --version-option=STRING  version option string
   --version-string=STRING      version string
   --no-discard-stderr          include stderr when parsing option output

  Report bugs to <bug-help2man@gnu.org>.
  gmake: *** [help2man.el.1] Error 255
  *** [do-build] Error code 1

  Stop in /usr/ports/misc/help2man.
  *** [/usr/ports/misc/help2man/work/.build_done.help2man._usr_local] Error code 1

  Stop in /usr/ports/misc/help2man.
  *** [build-depends] Error code 1

  Stop in /usr/ports/devel/autoconf.
  *** [/usr/ports/devel/autoconf/work/.configure_done.autoconf._usr_local] Error code 1

  Stop in /usr/ports/devel/autoconf.
  *** [build-depends] Error code 1

  Stop in /usr/ports/devel/automake.
  *** [/usr/ports/devel/automake/work/.configure_done.automake._usr_local] Error code 1

  Stop in /usr/ports/devel/automake.
  *** [build-depends] Error code 1

  Stop in /usr/ports/devel/apr1.
  *** [/usr/ports/devel/apr1/work/.configure_done.apr._usr_local] Error code 1

  Stop in /usr/ports/devel/apr1.
  *** [_apr1.realinstall] Error code 1

  Stop in /usr/ports/devel.
```

structure of customized ports tree

```
# ls
GIDs  Tools distfiles  net  xxxxxxxxxx  x11-fonts KNOBS  UIDs  doc   net-mgmt print  Makefile   bin   graphics   xxxxxxx security Makefile.inc converters   xxxx.sh  xxxxxxxxx  textproc Mk databases    lang        xxxxxxxxx   www Templates  devel    misc   xxxxxxxxxxxx    x11

 # ls devel
 autoconf-wrapper libevent   makedepend  py-asn1  py-setuptools automake  libltdl  p5-Locale-gettext py-asn1-modules swig13 Makefile  automake-wrapper libpthread-stubs pcre py-dateutil  zmq apr1  gettext libtool pkgconf py-protobuf autoconf    gmake  m4  protobuf py-pyzmq
```

By referring http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html

```
Note: You can build all the ports in a category or as a whole by running make in the top level directory, just like the aforementioned make fetch method. This is dangerous, however, as some ports cannot co-exist. In other cases, some ports can install two different files with the same filename.
```

Hope someone can help me out, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I hope you've resolved this by now. If not, **freebsd-ports@freebsd.org** or **hackers@freebsd.org** would be the best places to get answer to such questions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at the time the help2man port was out of date/broken. Additionally, when adding or removing categories and directories from ports, you need to edit Mk/bsd.port.mk to update the relevant list.

It's also possible that some ports have dependencies on ports that were removed. You can try running make index and see if it can cleanly build the index or not. This is a good clue on stability of at least default options in ports. (conditional dependencies wont' get tested)  Running portlint can also help validate a port and it's dependencies look OK.